# Get JSON Object by property with jq / bash

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

I have some JSON objects that looks like this

```
{
 "name": "thing1",
 "important_value": "42",
 "other_value": "27"
}
{
 "name": "thing2",
 "important_value": "13",
 "other_value": "5"
}
{
 "name": "thing3",
 "important_value": "788",
 "other_value": "58"
}
```

I need to get the value from only one of these object, but I only know the "name" value. I've tried somthing like this:

```
echo $objects | jq '.name == "thing2"'
```

I then get

```
false
true
false
```

But I need to get the values from this object, how do I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$objects" | jq 'select(.name == "thing2")'
```